# Little help with implementing Hookes law/elastic rope?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, physics, box2d, game-physics

Please refer to the video at

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_DyzwZJaDfM

The "brown" body is controlled with mouse and when mouse is pressed I calculate force using  Hookes law (refereed  to http://www.box2d.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=116 ) and the "blue" body should attract to the "brown" body.

But as seen in the video,"blue" body keep orbiting around and doesn't come stop.What I wanted to implement is "elastic rope" like thing.
First I tried using DistanceJoint ,but I cannot give a static distance to the joint.

here is my implementation for hookes law -

```
-(void)applyHookesLaw:(b2Body*)bodyA:(b2Body*)bodyB:(float) k:(float) friction:(float)desiredDist
{
    b2Vec2 pA=bodyA->GetPosition();
    b2Vec2 pB=bodyB->GetPosition();
    b2Vec2 diff=pB- pA;
    b2Vec2 vA=bodyA->GetLinearVelocity();
    b2Vec2 vB=bodyB->GetLinearVelocity();
    b2Vec2 vdiff=vB-vA;
    float dx=diff.Normalize();
    float vrel=vdiff.x * diff.x + vdiff.y * diff.y;
    float forceMag= -k*(dx-desiredDist);//-friction*vrel;
    diff*=forceMag;
    bodyA->ApplyForce(-1*diff,bodyB->GetPosition());

    //bodyA->wakeUp() 

}
```

Any tips please?

PS - gravity of the world is 0.0

Comment: you want the two bodies to finish up touching each other? How about doing what you already have, plus adding a weak mouse joint between the two bodies?

Comment: oh,it didnt occur to me before..thanks for the tip!

Comment: You could also add some friction, like air resistance. The behavior you see is correct, according to conservation of energy.

Comment: thanks for the tip.How can I set it in Box2d?

Comment: I have no idea. I know physics, not Box2d.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Hooke's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooke%27s_law) when incorporated into [Newton's Second law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_second_law#Newton.27s_second_law) is a second order differential equation: `m d^2 x/dt^2 = - k x`, where x is is a vector.  As Beta points out in the comments, you can just add friction. Absent a friction term, orbits like you observe are common, and they will continue indefinitely.  The usual way add friction is to add a term that is proportional to velocity, and like the Hookean term (`-k*x`), it is also negative, i.e. it opposes the motion.

If I'm reading your code correctly, you already have something like that term in the comments following setting `forceMag`.  But, I don't understand your calculation of `vrel`, it looks like the dot product between the relative velocity and the vector joining the two bodies.  `vdiff` is already the correct form for this.  Also, unlike the spring force, this force is directed along the relative velocity (`vdiff`).  So, to implement it I'd change the line where you call `ApplyForce` on `bodyA` to

```
bodyA->ApplyForce(-1*diff - friction*vdiff,bodyB->GetPosition());
```